# Tabulator adding new row is not applied custom sort defined

Tags: tabulator

I am using tabulator 4.8.4. I have tabulator defined with customer sort using sorter function in column. Sorting is applied properly during first load. When i add new row custom sorting is not applied.

```
table.addData([{
         orderNO: order.orderId,
        },false]);
```

It will be either inserted in the top or bottom based on the boolean value passed. I have to call below method to apply sort for newly added row

```
table.setSort(table.getSorters());
```

Now the problem is when ever new row added  table focus is moving to the top. Its very difficult to navigate rows mean while additional row is coming in. Every time row added foucs is moving to the top. I tried to get the current scroll position before adding new row

```
 scrollVertical:function(top){
        position = top;
        console.log('position'+top);
    }
```

But i did not find the way to set focus to this position after table redrwan. Please suggest and let me know am i doing anything wrong here

Answer (score 0):

The `addRow` or `addData` functions are specifically designed not to re-sort the table when a new row is added as this would be a very jarring experience for the user.

If you need to do this then i suggest that you use the `addRow` function and then call the `scrollTo` function on the new row to scroll it into view after the sort is finished

```js
table.addRow({orderNO: order.orderId})
.then((row) => {
    table.setSort(table.getSorters());
    row.scollTo();
});
```

Comment: I was able to make it work by setting  $(".tabulator .tabulator-tableHolder").scrollTop(position);